# UILabel position on device vs simulator not consistent

Tags: ios, iphone, storyboard, autolayout

I am testing my app on an iPhone 4 and iOS Simulator (4S). The label positioning is fine on the simulator but displays incorrectly on the device.

[image: 4S Simulator]
[image: iPhone 4]

I am using the following constraints on the label:

[image]

What could be causing this to happen?

Comment: What simulator displays is one thing, the more important thing is whether you constraints can be actually satisfied: from what I see the label might be too tall.

Answer (score 1):

You have a case of conflicting constraints. Let's step through the rules you applied to your label:

```
Align Center X to Superview
```

This is just aligning the center X of your superview with the center X of your label. No trouble here.

```
Bottom space to: SIGN UP <= 50
```

This constraint applies the rule "make the bottom of my label at MOST 50 points away from SIGNUP."

The issue is with your last constraint:

```
Top Space to: Top Layout Guide >= 5
```

This constraint adds the rule that the top space of your label must be AT LEAST 5 points away from the Top Layout Guide.

Auto Layout recognizes it can't possibly satisfy both the Bottom Space and Top Space constraints at the same time, so it destroys your bottom constraint, resulting in the bad behavior.

Your top constraint is still valid, because in that case the space between the top layout guide is greater than 5.

Try making your Top Layout Constraint a <=, or lowering the content compression resistance priority of your label.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in your constraint itself.

It shows that the topspace can be greater than or equal to 5. And bottom space can be less than or equal to 50. So that's why it shows such a behavior.

In my suggestion edit that constraints like:

```
Top Space equal to 5
Bottom Space less than or equal to 50
```